# Difficulty in solving an exercise about why product/coproduct is needed for 'words on the alphabet'.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, products

The following question is taken from Arrows, Structures and Functors by Arbib and Manes.

> For each set $A$, the set $A*$ of all 'words on the alphabet $A$' may be defined as

$$A*=\coprod_{n=0}^{\infty}A^n$$

> where $A^0=\{\land\}$ 'the empty word', $A^{n+1}=A^n\times A$).  Why can't we use an ordinary union"  [Hint:  Construct a set $A$ such that $A\cap(A\times A) \neq \emptyset$]

I try to create the non empty set in the hint, but this is my result:

$\text{If we have the alphabet}$ $\sigma=\{0,1\}$
and set $A=\{00, 01\}$, then for $n=2,$
$A\times A=A^2=\{0000, 0001, 0100, 0101\},$ $\text{don't we then have}$
$A\cap(A\times A)=\emptyset$, but with $A \cup (A\times A)=\{00, 01, 0000, 0001, 0100, 0101\}$

I am obviously doing something wrong.  My knowledge about formal language and automata are almost non existent other than knowing how to do rudimentary set theoretic operations with them.  Can someone give me some help me solving this question and also point out where I am going wrong or points my misunderstanding or insufficient understanding.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take $A=\{a, b,(a, b)\}$

Comment: @IsAdisplayName $A\times A=\{a^2, ab, a(a,b), ba, b^2, b(a,b)\}$, for $a=0$, $b=1$,
$A=\{0,1, (0,1)\},$ $A\times A=\{a^2, ab, a(a,b), ba, b^2, b(a,b)\}=\{0,0,0,0,1,(0,1),(0,1), (0,1)(0,1)\}$ and $A\cap (A\times A)=\{0,1, (0,1)\}$.  But after I found something that satisfied the hint, how does that show that ordinary union can't be used?

Comment: You would run into the problem that $(0,1)$ has both length 1, being a letter in your alphabet, and length 2, being a word using the letters 0 and 1. If you define a map in such a way that $(0,1)$ is not related to $0$ and $1$ (as you should be able to do), you won't be able to extend it to all the words, since the value at $(0,1)$ will be ill defined.

Comment: You should use the coproduct, not the product. You want the disjoint union of tha $A^n$, not 5he set of tuples with the $i$th entry in $A^i$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I did not know I can define set of words like $\{a,b, (a,b)\}$ meaning consisting of ordered pairs.  I know that for product, if I have two words, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then their product would simply be $\alpha\beta$.  Also, how do I define a map in such a way that (0,1) is not related to 0 and 1?  I mean what does it mean for (0,1) to not be related to 0 and 1?

Comment: You are interpreting elements of $A^n$ as "$n$ letter words", identifying the pair $(0,1)$ with the word $01$.

Comment: As for "not related"... you want the values of a function on an $n$ letter word to be competely determined by the values on the alphabet. But if your alphabet includes $2$ letter words, that can cause an unresolvable clash. Like trying to map $0$ to $a$, $1$ to $b$, and $(0,1)$ to $c$. But then you are supposed to map $01$ (which is the same as $(0,1)$ in this interpretation) to $ab$. So you need to send it to both $ab$ and to $c$, which is impossible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I thought the standard convention for writing (0,1) as 01?  Unless if I use coproduct for say $A=\{00,01\}$, then the coproduct of $A$ with itself is $A\sqcup A=\{(00,1), (01,1), (0000, 1), (0001,1), (0100,1), (0101,1)\}$

Comment: The question is: why are we using the coproduct/ disjoint union, instead of just the regular union? And my comments explain why having and element in both $A$ and $A^2$ causes an irresolvable difficulty if you try to use the union. Did you forget what the question was?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin is what you are talking about, about the "not related" bit, cover in standard text on formal languages Or is this a quirk of basic category theory apply to formal languages?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh it is asking me to try $A\coprod (A\times A)$ and compare it with $A\cup (A\times A)$.  Okay okay.

Comment: I explained exactly what I meant by "not related" and how it applies. It is not a formal term. This is an explanation of why you use the disjoint union when defining the set of words, rather than the union.

Comment: The question is, literally, "Why can't we use an ordinary union?" And your question was, allegedly, how finding an $A$ that intersects nontrivially with $A^2$ answers or helps answer that question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for the detail explanations.